# Why can't I push any commits for any of my repositories GitHub

Tags: github, github-for-windows

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length 185
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/WizardBoyd/Fyp-Game-Development-2024.git'
Enumerating objects: 76, done.
Counting objects: 100% (76/76), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (60/60), done.
Writing objects:  40% (24/60)
```

This is the error I keep getting with each of my repositories (change out the repo URL) my branch name by default is master (I have heard it should be changed to main which I have done but also been met with the same error)

I have both deleted and reinstalled both Git and GitHub desktop (I am on a Windows 10 machine) this issue only happens on my desktop as other machines can push just fine.

any suggestions?

tried reinstallation of GitHub desktop and git and deleting all related folders also I have tried checking for conflicting changes there are none.